# How to Rollback data inserted into 3 tables at once?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Please have a look at the below code

**DBHandler.java**

```
 @Override
    public String insertClient(String name, String address, String phone, String email, String country, Date visaGrantedDate, Date visaEntryDate)
    {
         int i=0;
       try
       {
           con.setAutoCommit(false);
           PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into Client (Name, Address, Phone, Email, Country, Visa_Granted_Date, Visa_Entry_Date) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
           ps.setString(1,name);
           ps.setString(2,address);
           ps.setString(3,phone);
           ps.setString(4, email);
           ps.setString(5, country);
           ps.setDate(6, visaGrantedDate);
           ps.setDate(7, visaEntryDate);

           i = ps.executeUpdate();
           con.commit();

           if(i>0)
           {
               return "Data saved successfully";
           }
           else
           {
               return "Error in saving data";
           }
       }
       catch(SQLException e)
       {
           try
           {
               con.rollback();
               e.printStackTrace();
               return "Failed to save data. Data safely rolled back";
           }
           catch(Exception ee)
           {
               ee.printStackTrace();
               return "Failed to save data. Data roll back failed";
           }
       }
    }

    @Override
    public String insertPortfolio(String portfolioID, String clientName, double amount, double dicn, String lawyer, String introducer, String provider, String Types)
    {
        int i=0;
       try
       {
           con.setAutoCommit(false);
           PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into Portfolio (portfolio_id, Client_Name, Amount, riteria_Net, Lawyer, Introducer, Provider, Types) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
           ps.setString(1,portfolioID);
           ps.setString(2,clientName);
           ps.setDouble(3,amount);
           ps.setDouble(4, dicn);
           ps.setString(5, lawyer);
           ps.setString(6, introducer);
           ps.setString(7, provider);
           ps.setString(8, Types);

           i = ps.executeUpdate();
           con.commit();

           if(i>0)
           {
               return "Data saved successfully";
           }
           else
           {
               return "Error in saving data";
           }
       }
       catch(SQLException e)
       {
           try
           {
               con.rollback();
               e.printStackTrace();
               return "Failed to save data. Data safely rolled back";
           }
           catch(Exception ee)
           {
               ee.printStackTrace();
               return "Failed to save data. Data roll back failed";
           }
       }
    }

    @Override
    public String insertClientFees(String portfolioID, double initialFees, double initialStepnaFees, double initialIntraFees, double ongoingFees, double ongoingStepnaFees, double ongoingIntraFees, double ongoingFabulaFees, double Fees, double otherFees, double VAT) 
    {
         int i=0;
       try
       {
           con.setAutoCommit(false);
           PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into Client_Fees (portfolio_id, Initial_Fees, InitiaFees2, Initial_intra_Fees, Ongoing_Fees, Ongoing_octa_Fees, Ongoing_intra_Fees, Ongoing_fabula_Fees, Ongoing_stepna_Fees, Other, VAT) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
           ps.setString(1,portfolioID);
           ps.setDouble(2,initialintraFees); 
           //Rest of the data insert code has been removed


           i = ps.executeUpdate();
           con.commit();

           if(i>0)
           {
               return "Data saved successfully";
           }
           else
           {
               return "Error in saving data";
           }
       }
       catch(SQLException e)
       {
           try
           {
               con.rollback();
               e.printStackTrace();
               return "Failed to save data. Data safely rolled back";
           }
           catch(Exception ee)
           {
               ee.printStackTrace();
               return "Failed to save data. Data roll back failed";
           }
       }
    }
```

What you just saw in the above code is how you can insert data into 3 different tables in the same database. However, the "form fields" for all of these 3 tables contain in one form, so all of these tables should be updated at once, and if something happens, data just inserted to all the 3 tables should be rolled back. For an example, below is how the database code is supposed to be called.

**MainUI.java**

```
dbConnector.insertClient(name, address, phone, email, country, null, null);

dbConnector.insertPortfolio(clientPortfolioId, name, amount, dicn, name, country, phone, visaEntryDate);

dbConnector.insertClientFees(clientPortfolioId, initialFees, initialVisionFees, initialintraFees, ongoingFees, ongoingStepnaFees, ongoingIntraFees, ongoingFabulaFees, ongoingserFees, otherFees, VAT)
```

So my question is, if something went wrong, how can I rollback the data just inserted to the all 3 tables at once?

Comment: You should use `TRANSACTION`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: Just rollback transaction

Comment: You should use the same `Connection` instance to execute all three statements. And then call `commit()` or `rollback()` once.
Each time you call `commit()` you cannot rollback what has been commited.

Comment: check http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-transaction-example/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should simply push up `try...catch` block from method outside them:

```
try {
     con.setAutoCommit(false);

     dbConnector.insertClient(...
     dbConnector.insertPortfolio(...
     dbConnector.insertClientFees(...

     con.commit();
} catch(SQLException e) {
     try {
          con.rollback();
          e.printStackTrace();
           return "Failed to save data. Data safely rolled back";
     } 
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what if the variable `i` is less than or equal to 0?

Comment: @Hope Sure, you can do rollback in this case also

Comment: hmm..OK, anyways, can it go less than 0 at any cost? If yes, then of course I have to implement the rollback, if it is not an accountable issue, then I have nothing to worry.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 transactions currently, one in each method. You need to have a single transaction (one `setAutoCommit(false)` and one `commit()` or `rollback()`).

So you'll need to refactor your code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your con.setAutoCommit(false); is good, but you may not do con.commit(); this before every 3 functions went through...

```
try {
  dbConnector.disableAutoCommit();
  dbConnector.insertClient(name, address, phone, email, country, null, null);

  dbConnector.insertPortfolio(clientPortfolioId, name, amountInvested, dicn, name, country, phone, visaEntryDate);

  dbConnector.insertClientFees(clientPortfolioId, initialEdenhurstFees, initialVisionFees, initialIntroducerFees, ongoingEdenhurstFees, ongoingVisionFees, ongoingIntroducerFees, ongoingCastleFees, ongoingEdenCastleFees, otherFees, VAT)

  dbConnector.commit();
} catch(Esxception e) {
  dbConnector.rollback();
}
```

more like this, and yout insert functions should not do the setAutocommit(false) and commit(), rollback() stuff and also do not catch the exceptions themself